# Karate: I get missing property in path $['data'] while using json filter path

Tags: karate

I have gone through karate documentation and questions asked on stack overflow. There are 2 json arrays under resp.response.data. I am trying to retrieve and assert "bId": 81 in below json from the resp.response.data[1] but I get this missing property error while retrieving id value 81.  Could you please help if I am missing something ?

```
     * def resp =
    """
    {
          "response": {
            "data": [
              {
                "aDetails": {
                  "aId": 15,
                  "aName": "Test",
                  "dtype": 2
                },
                "values": [
                  {
                    "bId": 45,
                    "value": "red"
                  }
                ],
                "mandatory": false,
                "ballId": "1231231414"
              },
              {
                "aDetails": {
                  "aId": 25,
                  "aName": "Description",
                  "dtype": 2
                },
                "values": [
                  {
                    "bId": 46,
                    "value": "automation"
                  },
                  {
                    "bId": 44,
                    "value": "NESTED ARRAY"
                  },
                  {
                    "bId": 57,
                    "value": "sfERjuD"
                  },
                  {
                    "bId": 78,
                    "value": "zgSyPdg"
                  },
                  {
                    "bId": 79,
                    "value": "NESTED ARRAY"
                  },
                  {
                    "bId": 80,
                    "value": "NESTED ARRAY"
                  },
                  {
                    "bId": 81,
                    "value": "NESTED ARRAY"
                  }
                ],
                "mandatory": true,
                "ballId": "1231231414"
              }
            ],
            "corId": "wasdf-242-efkn"
          }
        }
    """
    * def expectedbID=81
    * def RespValueId = karate.jsonPath(resp, "$.data[1][?(@.bId == '" + expectedbID + "')]")
    * match RespValueId[0] == expectedbID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are over-complicating things ?

```
* match resp.response.data[1].values contains { bId: 81, value: 'NESTED ARRAY' }
```